# linq List<A> select many <A,B>

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have:

```
List<string> sqlServerNames;
```

and a method:

```
List<string> GetDatabases( string serverName );
```

And I want a single query to get a list of { serverName, databaseName }

Is there a way to do this with Linq?

```
sqlServerNames.????
```

So for example, if I have two servers, ".", and "SQL2016".

```
And "." has "db1", "db2"
And "SQL2016" has "db3"
```

I'd want:

```
".", "db1"
".", "db2"
"SQL2016", "db3"
```

Probably with an anonymous type.

Comment: Do you want to get pair `{server, database}` or pair `{server, List of databases}`?

Comment: This first one. {server, database}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try something looks like this:

```
var tuples = sqlServerNames.SelectMany(server => GetDatabases(server).Select(db => Tuple.Create(server, db))).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

Recommend using another overload of `SelectMany`. The other answers will need to allocate a new enumerable/enumerator/delegate for each server name, while this doesn't.

```
sqlServerNames.SelectMany(serverName => GetDatabases(serverName),
                          (serverName, databaseName) => new
                          {
                              ServerName = serverName,
                              DatabaseName = databaseName
                          });
```

equivalent to:

```
from serverName in sqlServerNames
from databaseName in GetDatabases(serverName)
select new
{
    ServerName = serverName,
    DatabaseName = databaseName
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` method :

```
sqlServerNames
    .SelectMany(sn => GetDatabases(sn)
                        .Select(dbn => new { 
                                            ServerName = sn,
                                            DatabaseName = dbn 
                                            }
                                )
                );
```

Comment: I upvoted you as well, someone is downvoting everything on this question.  I like this better than the tuple but the tuple was first and it basically answered my question.

Comment: Anonymous type looks more pretty than tuple, so I upvoted.

Comment: @Derek; But the new tuple syntax is more clear (IMHO) : `.Select(dbn => (sn, dbn))`